# Bufferedreader fails to read whole file

Tags: java, xml, file, bufferedreader

so i got this weird error.
What i'm trying to do is this:

1. Open a zip file and then extracting the contents.
2. Iterate through the contents of the file and fix whitespaces of files aswell as the places the files are referenced, which is in several XMLs.
3. Zip contents.

Point 1 & 3 i've got covered - however when i try to read all the xml files, something is wrong.
I have all the xml files i want to read in an arraylist (about 30 files), and i then want to read them like this (note: this method is called in a for-loop which iterates over the 30 xml files):

```
private static void readXMLFile(String path) {
    // System.out.println("Deleting");
    Iterator<String> iter = listToRecreate.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        String str = iter.next();
        if (listToRecreate.size() > 0) {
            iter.remove();
        }
    }

    File mFile = new File(path);
    // System.out.println(path);
    // System.out.println("Beginning to read");

    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(mFile.getPath()));
        for (String sCurr = ""; (sCurr = br.readLine()) != null;) {
            // System.out.println(sCurr);
            listToRecreate.add(sCurr);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    editFile(path);
}
```

What then happens is that only half the content of the files are read. The weird thing is though, that if i pluck one xml file out and attempt to read that, it all works as it should. What could be the error here? 
Thanks in advance :)

EDIT:
How i write to file

```
private static void editFile(String path) {
    // System.out.println(path);
    try {
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new File(path));
        for (String str : listToRecreate) {
            // System.out.println(str);
            int j = 0;
            for (String tag : listOfTagNames) {
                str = replaceTag(str, listOfTagNames.get(j));
                j++;
            }
            // System.out.println(str);
            writer.println(str);
        }
        writer.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

EDIT 2:
I just realized that it might be my unzip method that is messing with me.
UPDATE: This code works now. Thanks to http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-unzip-the-contents-of-a-zip-file.html

```
public static void unzipFile(String filePath, String destPath) {
    try {
        ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(filePath);
        Enumeration<?> enu = zipFile.entries();
        while (enu.hasMoreElements()) {
            ZipEntry zipEntry = (ZipEntry) enu.nextElement();

            String name = zipEntry.getName();
            long size = zipEntry.getSize();
            long compressedSize = zipEntry.getCompressedSize();
            //System.out.printf("name: %-20s | size: %6d | compressed size: %6d\n",
                   // name, size, compressedSize);

            File file = new File(destPath + File.separator + name);
            if (name.endsWith("/")) {
                file.mkdirs();
                continue;
            }

            File parent = file.getParentFile();
            if (parent != null) {
                parent.mkdirs();
            }

            InputStream is = zipFile.getInputStream(zipEntry);
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = is.read(bytes)) >= 0) {
                fos.write(bytes, 0, length);
            }
            is.close();
            fos.close();

        }
        zipFile.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: @fge Just checked - yes i do

Comment: For information, to remove all the entries in the list, simply call `listToRecreate.clear()`. Where do you get the file path from? are you reading the file from the zip, then copying it into an actual file on disk?

Comment: Okay thanks @Lolo :) I'm copying a local zip file "something.zip" and create an edited copy "something_corrected.zip"

Comment: so your code is reading the zip file directly, not extracting the xml files inside and then reading them? If so, that's not the correct way to do it. Please clarify this in your question.

Comment: @Lolo No I extract the contents of the file, ofcoure - question updated. I extract the contents, modify them and zip them again with a new name :)

Comment: Nothing in your example indicates that files might be partially read. The only red flag to me is that we can't see where `listToRecreate` is declared -- perhaps you have some sort of race condition.

Can you provide a more complete example instead of just this method? Also, can you tell us _how_ you're determining the files aren't fully being read?

Comment: @Martin The way I determine that the whole file isn't being read, is that when the file has been written it is several kilobytes smaller than the original. As well as looking in the file - the copy contains < 100 lines while the original contains thousands of lines.

Comment: Any exceptions/stacktraces on your console? By the way, you should better use some logging framework instead of println and printStacktrace.

Comment: @UweAllner Nope, no exceptions nor stacktraces

Comment: @TheTazz Hasn't it occurred to you yet that maybe you aren't *writing* it correctly?

Comment: @EJP It might be that - I just don't see then. Also if I put a print after the line which reads the line in i can see that the whole document isn't being read.

Comment: @Martin The listToRecreate variable is just a simple ArrayList of string initialized at the top of the class as such: private static ArrayList<String> listToRecreate = new ArrayList<String>();

Comment: @TheTazz I recommend unzipping by hand and then comparing results, so you can isolate if the issue is with your zip code or your file reading code.

Comment: @Martin Yes, i have now done that and it seems that my unzip code is the problem ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who might find this in the future facing the same problem.
I discovered that it was my unzip method that didn't fully unzip my files, and that my read/write methods checked out.
I have updated the code so the unzip method works.

Thanks for everyone trying to help me out!